# reverse code items in a dataset in R

Tags: r

I am very new to R. I have a HW about data cleaning and it drives me crazy. I know it is very basic and simple for most of you but how can I reverse code items in R? In my data set there are 15 items, I need to reverse code 5 of them. In the dataset there are also some other variables such as age income etc. 
Please help me to reverse code the items.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for `?rev`? A minimal example would help understand what you're trying to do

Comment: Please post some code and data.

Comment: For item1, item2, item3, item4 and item5 I want to reverse code the response categories (5-point scale) such as 1=5, 2=4, 3=3, 4=2, 5=1

Comment: @Branda for the reverse coding you're describing, you could just do `dat$score <- 6-dat$score`, if `score` is the name of the variable that you wanted to reverse from 1->5 to 5->1.

Comment: Could you post some example data and desired output? I'm guessing you might want to work on R's "factor"s more formally. E.g. `x = factor(sample(1:5, 15, T)); x; levels(x) = list("1" = 5, "2" = 4, "3" = 3, "4" = 2, "5" = 1); x`